# issue with progress bar with web view in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

i have developed an application that have one web view and one progress bar so i want to add functionality like show progress in progress bar of loading web page so how it implement i have code that i put here.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progrss);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.technotalkative.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {



        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;

                }
        @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
    }


}


layout file..

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ProgressBar 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progrss"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/blue_progressbar"

        />      

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </WebView>



 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the issue? What is the problem?

Comment: issue is its no showing progress just showing progress bar

Comment: Need horizontal PB or circle type???

Comment: but i want use horizontal style like line......on top of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepare your   `progress bar` like

```
 progressBar.setProgress(0);
 probressbar.setMax(100);
```

You should set `intermediate progress` by using

```
progressBar.setProgress(int);
```

and implement your `WebViewClient` like this:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
//add this below line
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);

 if (progresss == 100) {
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 } else{
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Set progress in xml file for ProgressBar.

```
 <ProgressBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/progrss"
    android:progress="100"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/blue_progressbar"

    />
```

and in myWebClient method implement it

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use the following class. It will displaying progressbar while loading
>   the webpage.

```
 public class WebSearchActivity extends Activity{

        private WebView webView;

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.websearch);


            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(60);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new loadWebPage());

            pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pd.setMessage("Loading WebPage");
            pd.show();
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        }

        /*
         * This Class is used to get the WebView loading info
         */
        private class loadWebPage extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view,
                    final String url) {
                // load the given url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (pd.isShowing()) {
                    // dismiss the progress dialog
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {



            }

        }



    }
```